# How to find zerodivisor in a ring?

Tags: polynomials, ring-theory, roots-of-unity

Let $(F_2,+,\cdot)$ be the finite field with $2$ elements. We define the quotient ring $$R=F_{2}[X]/{\langle X^3\rangle}$$

Personal question: does $X^3$ have any roots in $R$? I would say no :/

1. How many elements does R have?

   $R$ has $2^3=8$ elements since $F_2$ has two elements and $3$ is the degree of    the polynomial $X^3$.

I am really confused about how to answer to the following questions, any suggestions? I would love to receive hints, I am not asking for the solution. Thanks.

2. Find a zerodivisor in the ring $(R, +, ·)$.
3. Find the multiplicative inverse of the element $X + 1 + \langle X^3\rangle$
4. How many elements does the set of units in R contain?

Comment: $X^3$ has always a root: $0^3=0$. Anyway, there is another root in $R$, which is $X+ \langle X^3 \rangle$.

Comment: Thanks.
Can you please explain me the last one?

Comment: Units are exactly represented by those polynomials which are coprime with $X$ (inside $F_2[X]$). That's because inside $F_2[X]$ two elements $a,b$ are coprime if and only if $\lambda a + \mu b = 1$ for some $\lambda, \mu$.

Comment: I am not following you, shouldn't we look for the roots in $F_2$?
Maybe you could suggest me a book/website where I could take a look on what you are saying?

Comment: You are confusing the $X$ of the ring $R[X]$ with the $X$ of the ring $F_2[X]$: they are not the same thing, and usually they are denoted by two distinct elements. For example, you should say $R=F_2[T]/ \langle T^3 \rangle$, and $R[X]= (F_2[T]/ \langle T^3 \rangle)[X]$. Now, with this notation, you are looking for units of $R$: these are exactly the polynomials coprime with $X^3$.

Answer (score 2):

> does $x^3$ have any roots in $R$? I would say no :/

Everything in the ideal generated by $X$ is a root of $f(x)=x^3$. These elements are: $0, X, X^2, X+X^2$.

> Find a zerodivisor

Well, $X^3=0$ already, and neither $X$ nor $X^2$ are zero, so we already have.

> Find the multiplicative inverse of the element $X + 1 + \langle X^3\rangle$

Handy to know: if $X^n=0$, then $X+1$ is a unit with inverse $1-X+X^2-X^3+...+(-1)^{n-1}X^{n-1}$. So, $(X+1)(1-X+X^2)=1+x^3=1$. In this way, $1+N$ is invertible for any nilpotent element $N$.

> How many elements does the set of units in R contain?

The ring is an Artinian local ring, so everything is either a unit or a zero divisor. We've already established that everything in $X+\langle X^3\rangle$ is nilpotent, and that $1+$ all of these elements is invertible. How many elements does that account for?

Comment: Is it correct to say the the zerodivisors are all the polynomials mutliples of $X3$?

Comment: @user158013 $X3$? You mean $X^3$?  what multiple of $X^3$ is $X+\langle X^3\rangle$?

Comment: Sorry I got confused.
Going back to your original question I would say that there are four invertibles elements: $1,1+X,1+X^2,1+X+X^2$

Comment: thank you for the explanation, it was really helpful.